# Rotating a projection matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix-multiplication, projection-matrix

In an OpenGL game, I am trying to rotate the camera relative to the player's view.  This rotation is not easily defined by relative angles, but rather easily defined by relative forward/up/left vectors.

How do I construct a matrix such that I can multiply it by the current projection matrix to achieve this rotation?

Comment: seems like setting the camera rotation to the forward vector will get you looking in the same direction.

Comment: To me its not really clear what your aiming for. Can you elaborate in more detail? Are you looking for player centric camera rotations? I.e. the player defines your coordinate system origin?

Comment: Sorry, it was hard for me to know enough to ask the right question.  I got what I needed by _initializing_ the modelview matrix to the relative orientation I wanted before the normal player orientation transforms were performed.  Doing this I was able to point the camera to up/left/right/back/top/down, all relative to where the player was currently looking, in order to capture a cubemap of their environment.